# Django: editing multiple existing model-entries based on a foreign key filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Am trying some things based on the initial setup of Myfirstapp tutorial.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

I've tried many different methods from other answers, but am getting errors or blank pages. So will ask a clean question.

I have the follow models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

And the following urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/editchoices/', views.ChoiceEditView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

I can show all choice_texts (and vote) related to a question through the url

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

and view

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
```

in combination with the template

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" name="csv" accept="csv/*"/><br />
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

I now want to create a page (form, view and template page) that gives me all choice_texts of choices related to a question (based on the pk in the url) in order to edit the multiple choice_texts (and save) and possible add 1 or 2 choices. I've tried a lot of code examples for modelformset, etc. but cannot get them to work. I already have LoginRequiredMixin and @login_required working in other views to limit this functionality to only registered users (once I get it to work), but don't want to use the admin part.

Working with Django version 2.0.4

I've tried with the following forms.py

```
class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        exclude = ('')

EditChoicesFormset = modelformset_factory(Choice, fields = ['choice_text'], exclude = [], can_delete = True, extra=1)
```

Comment: you have access to all `choices` related to a question with reverse_relation, `instance_question.choice_set.all()`

Comment: Thanks, I have that query working indeed to get the choice_texts, but how do I edit and save the alterations?

Comment: Add your form in the question

Comment: create your own form, not a ModelForm, add a `ModelMultipleChocieField`, that has a `queryset` from `Choice` model.... in your view, you can add the related choices like this: `form.fields['field_name'].queryset = instance_question.choice_set.all()`